# Unicorn master failed to start error

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I want to start unicorn, but it prints

```
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

And when I check logs nothing there. All settings with NGINX is OK! Because I work with it. But today it fail. How can I fix it?

In the unicorn log and nginx log are empty

When I try `service unicorn restart` it writes:

```
service unicorn restart
* Restarting Unicorn web server unicorn                                                                      start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 1702: No such process
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it seems ***unicorn.stderr.log*** file is missing in your app's log folder. I created this file manually and works fine for me.